# Ace editor pressing enter key does not add a newline

Tags: javascript, newline, ace-editor, enter, carriage-return

No newline is inserted when pressing the enter key in the editor field of an ace editor instance. Nothing happens.

Example initiation:

```
let codeEditor = ace.edit('someElementId', {
    minLines: 6,
    maxLines: 20,
    showLineNumbers: false,
    readOnly: false,
    newLineMode: 'auto',
});
codeEditor.setTheme('ace/theme/chrome');
codeEditor.session.setMode('ace/mode/json');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something else on your page is catching the event
On a page without other code your example works

```html
<form>
    <div id="someElementId"></div>
</form>

<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.3/ace.js></script>
<script>
let codeEditor = ace.edit('someElementId', {
    minLines: 6,
    maxLines: 20,
    showLineNumbers: false,
    readOnly: false,
    newLineMode: 'auto',
});
codeEditor.setTheme('ace/theme/chrome');
codeEditor.session.setMode('ace/mode/json');
</script>
```

Comment: Good call, I will look in to this (how did I not think of this?). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question so people who have a similar problem will save some time.

If this happens to you, `a user` was right. The event keypress event was manually caught, and stopped the event on enter manually somewhere else in the code.

If you need to debug this you can overwrite the preventDefault and/or the stopPropagation methods:

```
let debugPreventDefault = Event.prototype.preventDefault;
Event.prototype.preventDefault = function() {
    console.log(this);
    debugger;
    debugPreventDefault.call(this);
};
```

You might want to filter on this.type event types to skip certain events.